Can anybody help find chinece patent ZL201830612584.7
I'm stuck with this chinece patent number ZL201830612584.7 it's not looks like a normal patent number but on package of chinece healing plasters only this number mentionet as patent.
If somebody can say where to find it, thanks in advance!

Can you post a picture of the number on the product?

I do not think that is a valid Patent number.
The ZL is just a prefix for "Patent" and can be replaced with CN in most patent search databases.
Chinese Patent numbers are in the form:
yyyy t nnnnnnn.n

four digits for the year (y)
one digit for the type of patent right (t) (either 1, 2, or 3 for granted patents)
seven digits for the serial number (n) (This is a sequence number for applications filed in the year y)
one check digit (.n) (This is kinda like a single digit checksum based on the patent application number)

Applications and granted documents are both published with the same number.
So, for the number you gave, if we look up CN201830612584 we do not get any results. Notice this is looking for a Design patent (the 3 for the t value).
So we can change that digit to either a 1 or a 2 to see if there was any patent with the serial number 0612584 issued in 2018, e.g., check for either 201810612584 and 201820612584.
Of those two, the only valid Application number is CN201810612584, meaning that is the only application with that sequence number for 2018.

A kind of antibacterial biological degradable mulch
Abstract


The invention discloses a kind of antibacterial biological degradable mulch, are made of raw material from the following weight：30-50 parts of polyethylene, 60-80 parts of pueraria starch, 10-20 parts of lined polymethyl ethylene carbonate, starch -10-14 parts of methacrylic acid graft copolymer, 3-6 parts of nano-titanium dioxide, 4-8 parts of nano diatomite, 3-7 parts of nanoplant fiber, 1-5 parts of ozone oil, 1-4 parts of compatilizer, 2-6 parts of antibacterial Chinese herbal medicines powder, 2-5 parts of organic plasticizer, 3-8 parts of modification of chitosan, 2-5 parts of photodegradable aid, mulch of the invention can be effectively antibacterial, with excellent biological degradability, pest around mulch is few, anthelminthic effect is good, and mulch of the invention will not impact the production of plant；Raw material is easy to get, at low cost；The addition of nano-titanium dioxide, nano diatomite, the mechanical performance and water resistance of mulch significantly improve.

https://patents.google.com/patent/CN108912407A/en?oq=CN201810612584
Applicants: ANHUI JINGLIANG TONGSHUO PLASTIC FILM TECH CO LTD
Inventors: SHENG CHENGLIN; CHEN LIHUA; LIU XIAN
Filed 6/14/2018
Published 11/30/2018
Withdrawn 5/14/2019

Thanks a lot Andrew for a detailed answer!
